# Generate Random Data in the Form of a Letter

Tags: r, random

I couldn't found anything on this task while Googling, but I can't imagine no one has thought of doing this. Is there a way to generate random 2d data in the form of a letter of choice? So basically a function `letter_random_data(letter)` that would output `x` and `y` coordinates (within some boundaries) that together with some noise form the chosen letter.

Comment: not entirely clear what you're asking.  Do you want to take x-y coordinates that form a letter (with random rotation and shifts?) and add some noise?

Comment: Precisely, I'll edit my question.

Comment: Not with raw random data.  You could do it with random data as input to a genetic algorithm which, if it works correctly, will approach the chosen letter.  If you stop it short, it will give you a noisy letter rather than the finished product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:  Draw an image containing the letter (or text, more generally).  Read the image into an array, and use it to accept or reject points drawn randomly in the box holding the image.

For example,

```
library(png)

getTextImage <- function(text) {
  filename <- tempfile()
  png(filename = filename)
  plot.new()
  cex <- 1
  repeat {
    if (strwidth(text, cex = 2*cex) > 1) break
    if (strheight(text, cex = 2*cex) > 1) break 
    cex <- 2*cex
  }
  text(0.5, 0.5, text, cex = cex)
  dev.off()
  image <- readPNG(filename)
  unlink(filename)    # clean up file
  if (length(dim(image)) == 3)
    image <- image[,,1] # just keep one channel
  image
}

randomText <- function(n, text) {
  image <- getTextImage(text)
  nx <- dim(image)[1]
  ny <- dim(image)[2]
  hits <- 0
  x <- y <- numeric(n)
  while (hits < n) {
    tryx <- runif(1)
    tryy <- runif(1)
    keep <- image[round((nx-1)*tryx + 1), round((ny-1)*tryy + 1)] == 0
    if (keep) {
      hits <- hits + 1
      # Need to rotate so it looks good
      x[hits] <- tryy
      y[hits] <- 1 - tryx
    }
  }
  cbind(x, y)
}

plot(randomText(1000, "Hello"))
```

This produces the following plot:

[image: screenshot]